# How do I print out "No Output" if the program doesn't find any solution (C Language)

Tags: c

This is my program.  I found that if I input n>480, the program wouldn't output any solution. How do I express it and print "No Output" in this program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()

{ int x,y,z,n;
scanf("%d",&n);
for(x=0;x<=n;x++)
for(y=0;y<=n;y++)
for(z=0;z<=n;z++)

if(5*x+2*y+0.1*z==120&&x+y+z==n)
printf("%d,%d,%d\n",x,y,z);
}
```

Comment: Initialize a counter to 0 before your loops and increment it inside the `if` statement. Outside of your loops, check if that counter is equal to zero and print the message you want

Comment: Whatever book or course is teaching you to write `main()` instead of `int main(void)` (or perhaps, but less good, `int main()`) should be discarded now.  It is teaching you bad habits.  Not specifying the return type has been invalid for over 2 decades now.  And the fact that you're able to compile it means you are compiling with an antiquated compiler — and yes, GCC 4.x is old.  GCC 5.x and later default to C11.  You should be using at least C99.  You should not be using C90, which allows what you wrote.

Comment: You should be using more space, both indenting the code and spaces within lines.  It is hard to read such squished, unintended code.  And the blank line between the erroneous `main()` and the `{` is unwanted — at least, in all the coding standards I've seen.

Comment: IMNSHO, it is much easier to read `if (5*x + 2*y + 0.1*z == 120 && x + y + z == n)` — or even `if (5 * x + 2 * y + 0.1 * z == 120 && x + y + z == n)` — than what you wrote (`if(5*x+2*y+0.1*z==120&&x+y+z==n)`).  Mixing the floating-point number in the calculation raises issues with the accuracy of floating-point arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try counting the true-branch passes in the loops, as pointed out by Alex P:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    int results = 0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int x=0;x<=n;x++) {
        for(int y=0;y<=n;y++) {
            for(int z=0;z<=n;z++) {
                if(5*x+2*y+0.1*z==120 && x+y+z==n) {
                    printf("%d,%d,%d\n", x,y,z);
                    results++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
        
    if (results == 0) {
        printf("No results\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: The final `printf()` format string should end with a newline.  Is there really a good reason not to use `for (int x = 0; x <= n; x++)` rather than defining the loop controls outside the loop block?  That's been valid for 20+ years.

Comment: Yes, both points are valid. I had only amended the OP's code with minimal formatting. I updated my answer.

Comment: Also note that the second part of the condition leaves a chance to optimize out the z loop by calculating the value directly. Since this looks like homework, I leave the details out here.